# SAS: How to create a (date variable) dataset

Tags: sas

I would like to know how to create a (date/time) column in my data set with a comma delimiter. A few months ago I googled around and figured how to, but I accidently deleted that file and couldn't find the ways anymore...

I think it's something to do with `input`, any tips?

```
data INPUT;
infile datalines delimiter=','; 
input CINNUMBER $1-8 DATE $10-20;
datalines;
AB12345C, 01/01/2017
;
RUN;
```

Thank you, George

Comment: Wondering why the question is titled SAS PROC SQL :)?

Comment: @Richard Because these are input are fed into my PROC SQL queries, but I have updated the title. Thanks Richard!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DATA INPUT;
  infile datalines delimiter=','; 
  attrib
    CINNUMBER length = $8
    DATE length = 8 format = mmddyy10. informat = mmddyy10.
  ;
  input CINNUMBER DATE ;
datalines;
AB12345C, 01/01/2017
;
RUN;
```

SAS has a few [styles of input](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=n1w749t788cgi2n1txpuccsuqtro.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en).  The above demonstrates *list input*.  This is probably the safest style for comma separated data.  The `ATTRIB` statement defines the variables and their attributes before the `INPUT` statement.  Input processing will use the `INFORMAT` `MMDDYY10.` for reading the mm/dd/yyyy data field into your `DATE` variable.